# How do I access my node.js website from an external device?

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04, external, vmware

I have a node.js website running on my Ubuntu VM. I can access it both from the host and the VM. But if I try http://192.168.10.120:80, from an external device connected to the same network over WiFi, it doesn't work.

What I need to do to make the web site accessible to external devices on the same local network?

I've been googling this for days, and still can't find an answer...

Comment: In addition to the firewall advice already posted, make sure your program is listening on host `0.0.0.0` rather than `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @apsillers, just tried it out, and it does indeed..

Answer (score 1):

If the host is Windows, there's two things you'll have to do. One is setting up port forwarding in your VM settings. If you're using Virtual Box check [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/) out. Also, depending on your internal networking setup, you may need to allow inbound connections to port 80 through Windows Firewall. Check out this [article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7) from Microsoft. The process hasn't really changed since Windows 7 so it should be the same on 8 or 10.

As a side note, security through obscurity sucks but I still wouldn't recommend using port 80.

Comment: Also, I'm sure sure what IP you were trying to hit, but after setting up the port forwarding you'll need to hit the local IP of your host machine, not the IP of the VM. Setting up the port forwarding is essentially telling your computer to route incoming port 80 traffic on your computer to port 80 on the VM.

Comment: I don't really care about port 80, I can set it anything else bigger than 1024... and I am using VMware, not Virtual Box

Comment: Looks like for VMware it's at Edit > Virtual Network Settings > NAT > Edit > Port Forwarding, but you may have to look around for it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know